# Update other menus based on selection from another menu

Tags: r, shiny, updates, observers

I currently have a Shiny app with 3 menus (more to be added once the bugs are worked out).
I have found examples online of a top down menu filtering approach. Meaning the user must select from the first menu, then the second menu, and so on, but in order. If they select from the 2nd menu first then it does not filter the first menu, only the ones below it and obviously that is a problem.
I want my users to be able to jump around to the menus in any order and have them filter.
In my example there are 3 menus, and what I am trying to do is if `observeEvent` on **any** menu (user makes a selection from any menu) then:

1. Filter the data based on the selection made
2. `updateSelectInput` for any menus that have no input selected yet

This will ensure that the menus are up to date with what is actually in the data and ensures that the user doesn't slice down to something that does not actually exist in the data.
Also, **note** that step #2 is very important - only update menus with no selection made, I have had issues with this because if I just update all other menus then it clears the user selected input, which is still the wrong behavior.
I know what I need to do but I have not been able to pull it off yet, so the help is appreciated.

**Update**
I updated my code to work with the one answer posted below but it still does not quite work correctly.
Now it does filter down the menus, however, once the subset has been created, it does not allow for it to "filter" back up.
What I mean by this is that If I select the value `3` from the first menu `TreeNumber` then the last menu filters down to just the value `300` - that is good.  *BUT* if I then go back to the first menu and also select the value `4`, I expect that the `Circumference` menu will now show the values: `300` and `400`, however, it still only shows the value `300`.

Updated Code:

```
d <- data.frame("TreeNumber" = c(replicate(7, 1), replicate(7, 2), 
                                 replicate(7, 3), replicate(7, 4)),
                "TreeAge" = c(1:28),
                "Circumference" = c(replicate(7, 100), replicate(7, 200), 
                                    replicate(7, 300), replicate(7, 400)))
col_names <- names(d)
# TODO - change these to: "Tree Number", "Tree Age", "Circumference"
user_friendly_names <- c('TreeNumber', 'TreeAge', 'Circumference')

ui <- fluidPage(  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3("Filters:"),
      uiOutput("filters"),

      # Plot button
      fluidRow(column(2, align = "right",
                      actionButton("plot_graph_button", "Plot")))
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("summary"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #### Create the filter lists for UI ####
  output$filters <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(col_names)) return(NULL)
    lapply(1:length(col_names), function(i) {
      col <- paste0(col_names[i])
      alias <- user_friendly_names[i]
      # Populate input with unique values from column
      pickerInput(inputId = alias, label = paste(alias,':'),
                     choices = unique(d[[col]]), multiple = T)
    })
  })


  # lapply(X = vars, FUN = function(x) {
  #   vals <- sort(unique(data[[x]]))
  #   updatePickerInput(session = session, inputId = x, choices = vals)
  # })

  my_filter <- function(data, var) {
    # TODO - Need to convert from user_friendly_names --> col_names in here
    if (length(input[[var]]) == 0) return(data)
    data %>% subset(data[[var]] %in% input[[var]])
  }  

  subsettedData <- reactive({
    d %>% my_filter("TreeNumber") %>% my_filter("TreeAge") %>%
      my_filter("Circumference")
    # TODO - get into for loop versus hard coding this step:
    # for(z in 1:length(col_names)){
    #   d %>% my_filter(col_names[z])
    # }
  })

  observeEvent(subsettedData(), {
    lapply(col_names, function(var) {
      selections <- unique(subsettedData()[[var]])
      if (length(input[[var]]) == 0)
        updatePickerInput(session = session, inputId = var, choices = selections)
    })
  }) 


  observeEvent(input$plot_graph_button, {
    for (j in seq_along(d)) {
      updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = user_friendly_names[j], 
                        choices = c("All", unique(d[[j]])), selected = "All")
    }
  })


  output$summary <- renderTable({
    # Do not show a plot when the page first loads
    # Wait until the user clicks "Plot" button
    if (input$plot_graph_button == 0){
      return()
    }
    # Update code below everytime the "Plot" button is clicked
    input$plot_graph_button

    isolate({
      # Fresh copy of the full data set every time "Plot" button is clicked
      d <- copy(Orange)

      # Filter data based on UI
      for(f in 1:length(col_names)){

        if(eval(parse(text = paste0('is.null(input$',user_friendly_names[f],')')))){
          # Default to "All" - do not filter
          print("All")
        }else{                
          d <- d[d[[col_names[f]]] == 
                    unlist(eval(parse(text = 
                       paste0('input$',user_friendly_names[f])))), ]
        }
      }
      final_summary_table <<- d
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: (Where is `copy` defined?) Can you do this with `shiny::updateSelectizeInput`?

Comment: @r2evans `copy` is a function. Just taking copies of the data to ensure I don't write over anything. I imagine that `update____` will be used in the solution, yes.

Comment: @r2evans copy is in the data.table namespace to create a deep copy of a data.table object. It can also be applied to data.frames in which case it acts like as.data.table.

Comment: My bad ... I did a generic `??copy` and it did not return `data.table::copy` (and I am not overly familiar with `data.table`), but I see (manually) that it's there. Thanks. (Of course, now `??copy` *is* returning that function, so I need more -- or less -- caffeine.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an app that applies filtering based on all inputs. I'm not sure how intuitive it is to give a selection called "all" in a `selectInput` with `multiple = TRUE`. Maybe It would be better to add a reset button for each selection instead.

I replaced the dataset `Orange` with `tips` to get more factor variables. Also, I didn't use `data.table` in the example since it seems irrelevant for your problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data(tips, package = "reshape2")
filter_vars <- c("sex", "smoker", "day", "time")

ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(filter_vars, function(var) {
    selectInput(var, var, unique(tips[[var]]), multiple = TRUE)
  }),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_filter <- function(data, var) {
    if (length(input[[var]]) == 0) return(data)
    data %>% subset(data[[var]] %in% input[[var]])
  }  

  subsettedData <- reactive({
    tips %>% my_filter("sex") %>% my_filter("smoker") %>% 
      my_filter("day") %>% my_filter("time")
  })

  observeEvent(subsettedData(), {
    lapply(filter_vars, function(var) {
      selections <- unique(subsettedData()[[var]])
      if (length(input[[var]]) == 0)
        updateSelectInput(session, var, choices = selections)
    })
  })   

  output$table <- renderTable({ subsettedData() })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I used my code example just to keep things simplified but in my more complex code I do away with `All`, because it is not a good way to handle the menus as you did point out.

Comment: Your code produces a text input menu, mine is a drop down menu. This code is not similar enough to my example for it to work in the way I need it to. In your example, when something is deleted, it is gone and that is a flaw.

Comment: See my edited solution. For me it was not clear that the sub-setting should be reversible.

Comment: For this section: `subsettedData <- reactive({
    tips %>% my_filter("sex") %>% my_filter("smoker") %>% 
      my_filter("day") %>% my_filter("time")
  })` is there a way to avoid hard coding each category?

Comment: Yes, you can just use a for loop over the variable names and replace the data with the filtered one every time

Comment: Also take a look at `shinyWidgets::pickerGroupServer` for an out-of-the-box solution for this

Comment: I updated the question to include your answer. It does filter the menus, however, it doesn't reverse filter. Meaning once the data set is filtered down, it cannot go back up if more selections have been made. (I explained this in more detail in the edit to my question up above)